# Oracle Coherence - Distinct Values from combination of columns

Tags: oracle-coherence

I want to build query that retrieves distinct values based on two columns in the Oracle Coherence grid. Grid for example contains columns
InvoiceID, ProductName, Description, BookedAtTime, Updated By (etc...)

The columns combination to retrieve distinct values is ProductName-BookedAtTime, so any record with distinct Product and BookedAtTime should be extracted. This is a high volume grid with millions of records in it and I need to keep looking at the new values on certain time interval.

I tried to explore Coherence documentation to find a way to build this query, 
i could find DistinctValues filter http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/coherence/341/com/tangosol/util/aggregator/DistinctValues.html

however, the constructor only allows a string. I need to know which filter could be used to build

- Query that could be used here to extract values
- Best approach to continually retrieve data from Coherence grid in
  high volume scenario like this.

I am new to Coherence and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

the class has below constructor:

```
DistinctValues(ValueExtractor extractor)
```

You can use MultiExtractor to get the property combinations.

> MultiExtractor: Composite ValueExtractor implementation based on an array of extractors. All extractors in the array are applied to the same target object and the result of the extraction is a List of extracted values.
>
> Common scenarios for using the MultiExtractor involve the DistinctValues or GroupAggregator aggregators, that allow clients to collect all distinct combinations of a given set of attributes or collect and run additional aggregation against the corresponding groups of entries.
>
> see:
> http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/coherence/341/com/tangosol/util/extractor/MultiExtractor.html